# Convert elements in an array of Int to elements of another array of String using map and filter

Tags: swift

I have an array of integers `var array: [Int] = [0, 1, 2]`

I have an array of strings `var arrayOfStrings: [String] = ["apple", "banana", "orange"]`

I have a function that i can pass an array parameter of Int and returns an array of String.

If i call the function and pass the following Int array [0, 1] which means that the user selected apple and banana, i need to return from that function the array of string with apple and banana from the second array which means ["apple", "banana"]. How is this possible using map and filter in swift? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you don't need the first array. You should always use the original array indices.

```
let indices = arrayOfStrings.indices // note that it is a Range not an array
```

---

You just need to iterate the selected indices and map the original array:

```
let selectedIndices: [Int] = [0, 1]

let selectedElements = selectedIndices.map { arrayOfStrings[$0] }
selectedElements
```

Another option is to use an indexset:

```
let selectedIndices: IndexSet = [0, 1]

let selectedElements = selectedIndices.map { arrayOfStrings[$0] }
```

Comment: I think using `selectedIndices.indices.map` instead of `selectedIndices.map` means the values in the array are ignored. This example only works because [0,1] are both the indices and the contents of the array.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth Absolutely. My bad thanks. Copy/paste editing error.